# AS2: don't perform rollout until motion finished

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I have an mc with some tweens applied to it, but if you roll out before they are done they break. I don't want to disable the button while tweens are running because if you roll out while they run you confuse the user because nothing happens and you get stuck in that frame.

What I want is to acknowledge the rollout during the tween (or after) but not run until the tweens are finished. I cannot seem to access the onmotionfinished of the tween in the rollover function from the rollout function however.

Any ideas?

If it helps here is my rollover:

```
    buttons[i].onRollOver = function() {
    var oppX:Number = Stage.width-this._x;
    var oppY:Number = Stage.height-this._y;
    if (oppX-209.8<=20) {
        var difference:Number = Math.abs(20-(oppX-209.8));
        oppX += difference;
    } else if (oppX+209.8>=780) {
        var difference:Number = Math.abs(780-(oppX+209.8));
        oppX -= difference;
    }
    if (oppY-172.1<=20) {
        var difference:Number = Math.abs(20-(oppY-172.1));
        oppY += difference;
    } else if (oppY+172.1>=580) {
        var difference:Number = Math.abs(580-(oppY+172.1));
        oppY -= difference;
    }
    var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(circle, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle._x, oppX, 1, true);
    var TweenY:Tween = new Tween(circle, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle._y, oppY, 1, true);
    circle.gotoAndPlay("out");
    myColor = new Color(this);
    myColor.setTint(153,255,0,30);
    for (MovieClip in buttons) {
        delete buttons[MovieClip].onEnterFrame;
        if (buttons[MovieClip] != this) {
            buttons[MovieClip].enabled = false;
            myColor = new Color(buttons[MovieClip]);
            myColor.setTint(255,255,255,80);
            myColor = new Color(buttons[MovieClip]._line);
            myColor.setTint(255,255,255,80);
        }
    }

};
```

and my rollOut:

```
    buttons[i].onRollOut = function() {
    this.onMotionComplete = function() {

    var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(circle, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle._x, 400, 0.5, true);
    var TweenY:Tween = new Tween(circle, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle._y, 300, 0.5, true);
    TweenY.onMotionFinished = function() {
        for (MovieClip in buttons) {
            buttons[MovieClip].enabled = true;
        }
    };
    this._parent.circle.gotoAndPlay("in");
    for (MovieClip in buttons) {
        buttons[MovieClip].onEnterFrame = function() {
            moveButtons(this);
            controlButtons(this);
        };
        myColor = new Color(buttons[MovieClip]);
        myColor.setTint(255,255,255,0);
    }

};
```

Comment: `_currentframe` and `_totalframes` are your good friends.

Comment: it is an actionscript tween i'm afraid. single framed.

Comment: Are you using an enterFrame to manually tween your object or are you using a tweening library ? If it's a tweening library it should have an event handler/callback for animation complete. If you're animating onEnterFrame you can check if the current position of your object is the final position.

Comment: hmmm...just read 'onmotionfinished'. Does that mean your using the tween classes that come with flash (mx.motion.Tween) ? If so, you will have a function for the rollOver part, but it will not be assigning yet. In the onMotionComplete handler you will assign the rollover function (e.g. myTweenedObj.onRollOver = myRollOverFunction;)

Comment: Yep using the tween class, the problem is that doesn't allow the rollOver to be noticed until the motion is over, so if they roll out before the tween is finished they are stuck. I need to have a constant roll out function that can tell when the motion is finished and then run. So if they roll out during the tween the roll out happens it just waits for the tween to finish, but the tween in the rollover function doesn't appear to be scopable from the rollout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised that it wasn't the tween causing most of the problems that it was the gotoandplay because i had my stop(); calls on the same frame as the markers on that movieclip causing them to get stuck.

Did have some trouble with tween (the rollout jumped back to the rollover position if its tweens were called mid tween) but I decided to push the tweens to an array making them globally accessible and purge the array onmotionfinished then in the rollout check to see if the array contains anything and if so kill off the old tweens first.

Final product:

```
    buttons[i].onRollOver = function() {
    circle.active = this;
    var oppX:Number = Stage.width-this._x;
    var oppY:Number = Stage.height-this._y;
    if (oppX-209.8<=20) {
        var difference:Number = Math.abs(20-(oppX-209.8));
        oppX += difference;
    } else if (oppX+209.8>=780) {
        var difference:Number = Math.abs(780-(oppX+209.8));
        oppX -= difference;
    }
    if (oppY-172.1<=20) {
        var difference:Number = Math.abs(20-(oppY-172.1));
        oppY += difference;
    } else if (oppY+172.1>=580) {
        var difference:Number = Math.abs(580-(oppY+172.1));
        oppY -= difference;
    }
    var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(circle, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle._x, oppX, 1, true);
    var TweenY:Tween = new Tween(circle, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle._y, oppY, 1, true);
    TweenY.onMotionFinished = function () {
        tweens.length = 0;
    }
    tweens.push(TweenX,TweenY);
    circle.gotoAndPlay("out");
    myColor = new Color(this);
    myColor.setTint(153,255,0,30);
    for (MovieClip in buttons) {
        delete buttons[MovieClip].onEnterFrame;
        if (buttons[MovieClip] != this) {
            buttons[MovieClip].enabled = false;
            myColor = new Color(buttons[MovieClip]);
            myColor.setTint(255,255,255,80);
            myColor = new Color(buttons[MovieClip]._line);
            myColor.setTint(255,255,255,80);
        }
    }
};
buttons[i].onRollOut = function() {
    if (tweens.length != 0) {
        tweens[0].stop();
        tweens[1].stop();
        delete tweens[0];
        delete tweens[1];
        tweens.length = 0;
    }
    circle.gotoAndPlay("in");
    var TweenX:Tween = new Tween(circle, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle._x, 400, 0.5, true);
    var TweenY:Tween = new Tween(circle, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle._y, 300, 0.5, true);
    TweenY.onMotionFinished = function() {
        circle._x = 400;
        circle._y = 300;
        for (MovieClip in buttons) {
            buttons[MovieClip].enabled = true;
        }
    };
    for (MovieClip in buttons) {
        buttons[MovieClip].onEnterFrame = function() {
            moveButtons(this);
            controlButtons(this);
        };
        myColor = new Color(buttons[MovieClip]);
        myColor.setTint(255,255,255,0);
    }
};
```